# iFrame dynamic height with multiple iFrames

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dynamic

I am trying to build a web widget via iframe that automatically adjusts the height as you resize the browser. Everything works fine with a single widget but as soon as you load a second one, the dynamic height is not working anymore.

I send the height from within the iframe to its parent and an event listener is catching the message and adjusting the height accordingly. This works great. However I need to know which iframe is sending which height property to be able to resize them properly.

My current idea is to count the messages that the parent page receives and then loop through all the widget iframes in the page. The problem is that if I don't know where the height value comes from, it sets all iframes to the height that was last sent.

**This is the code in the iframe:**

```
// pass iframe height to parent
window.addEventListener('load', iframeHeightHandler);
window.addEventListener('resize', iframeHeightHandler);

function iframeHeightHandler() {

    let height = document.body.scrollHeight;

    //window.top refers to parent window
    window.top.postMessage(["setHeight", height], "*");
}
```

**This is the code in the parent page:**

```
    // reset height to actual height
    const widgets = document.querySelectorAll("div[data-watermark]");
    let msgNumber = 0;
    window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        let eventName = e.data[0];
        let data = e.data[1];
        switch(eventName) {
            case 'setHeight':
            for (let i=0; i<widgets.length; i++) {
                if (i == msgNumber) {
                    widgets[i].querySelector('.frame-'+i).style.height = data + 'px';
                }
            }
            if (msgNumber+1 == widgets.length) {
                msgNumber = 0;
            } else {
                msgNumber++;
            }
            console.log('Message ' + msgNumber + ' ' + data);
            break;
        }
    } , false);
```